# How to unsubscribe Dexie Hook

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

Using following working code:

```
db.table(this.mytableName).hook('creating', function (primKey, obj, transaction) {
   currentObj.countUnsync();      // Call function 1
   currentObj.uploadUnsyncToDB(); // Call function 2
});
```

I need to stop the  listening to the hook 'creating'.

According docs this should work but it does not for me as i do not know what **'yourListenerFunction'** to use.

```
db.table(this.mytableName).hook('creating').unsubscribe(yourListenerFunction)
```

Can anyone help with an example.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation refers to yourListenerFunction as the function you pass as a second argument to hook('creating'). You would need to give that function a name or store a reference to it somewhere in order to unsubscribe to it.

I just now [updated the docs](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.hook(%27creating%27)#to-unsubscribe) with regards to this question to make the docs a little bit clearer:

*yourListenerFunction* refers to the same function instance that you have passed to Table.hook('creating'). If you will need to unsubscribe, you can't inline that function as we do in the main sample. Instead keep a reference to it in a closure or on a class property.

```js
function listenerFunction (primKey, obj, transaction) {
  // Do your stuff...
}

// Subscribe:
db.[tableName].hook('creating', listenerFunction);

// Unsubscribe:
db.[tableName].hook('creating').unsubscribe(listenerFunction);
```